# MongoDB - Return id of inserted item

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

From following the below tutorial

https://codeforgeek.com/2015/08/restful-api-node-mongodb/

I have the following to create an order in my database

```
exports.createOrder = function(req,res){
  var db = new mongoOp();
  var response = {};

  db.userId = req.body.userId;
  db.userEmail =  req.body.userEmail;
  db.userOrder = req.body.userOrder;

  db.save(function(err){
      if(err) 
      {
        response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error adding data"};
      } 
      else 
      {
          response = {"error" : false,"message" : "Data added"};
      }
      res.json(response);
  });

}
```

How can I return the id of the inserted item from the DB.save() along with the response ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback function of a `db.save()` function takes two parameters where the second parameter would give you the inserted or updated **result**. If you do not provide the `_id` with the data to be saved, **mongodb** will generate an **id** and assign it to the key of `_id`.

So if you try to get `_id` from **result**, you would find something like this: `ObjectId("50691737d386d8fadbd6b01d")` and you can add it to you your **response** object.

```
db.save(function(err, result){
  if(err) {
    response = { error: true, message: "Error adding data" };
  } else {
    response = { error: false, message: "Data added", id: result._id };
  }
  res.json(response);
});
```

Hope the answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The save function returns a WriteResult object which contains as property the id of the added object.  view [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#writeresults-save), so try to log it like below and see what you get.

```
db.save(function(err, result){
      if(err) 
      {
        response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error adding data"};
      } 
      else 
      {
          console.log(result._id);
          response = {"error" : false,"message" : "Data added"};
      }
      res.json(response);
  });
```