# Returning id from newly inserted document - mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to insert a document into a MongoDB collection *and* have the ID of the newly created document returned. The insertOne() method (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/#db-collection-insertone) would be perfect for this - however my current version of Mongo is limited to the insert() method (documentation on the same page linked above). This method does not return the object_id of the inserted document(s) - same goes for the save() method.

collection.insert():

```
> db.urls.insert({"url":"https://www.google.com"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

collection.save():

```
> db.urls.save({"url":"https://www.google.com"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Is there a more suitable method for me to use here?

I see a possible answer in this post: [MongoDB - Return id of inserted item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662875/mongodb-return-id-of-inserted-item), however I'm not sure if the save() method they're using is the same one I'm looking at, since it appears to be acting on the database object versus the collection. I tried following the example in the top answer with entering this code:

```
db.urls.save(function(err,result) 
    { response = {id:result._id} 
    res.json(response) 
})
```

Received a generic syntax error after entering this into the mongo shell.

Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

So I've realized my question is more about the Node.js *driver* for MongoDB rather than MongoDB itself - from my experiences with SQL - my question wouldn't be as relevant if I were asking how to retrieve the ID of a newly inserted record in SQL Server - this task is more the responsibility of the driver. Looking at the documentation for the Node.JS driver provided in the possible duplicate post - this has exactly the answer I'm looking for:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#insert

Going off this documentation, the following code gives me exactly what I need:

```
 db.urls.insert({"url":"https://www.google.com"}, function(err, docs) {
     console.log(docs);
 })
```